# Can we invoke an apex class from a Schedulable Class?

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

Can we invoke an apex class(not batch apex class) from a Schedulable Class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can call any public class you want from the schedulable context. There are no limitations that would prevent you from calling public static methods:

```
public void execute(SchedulableContext context)
{
    MyClass.doStuff(/*parameters*/);
}
```

Nor any limitations that would prevent you from calling public instance methods:

```
public void execute(SchedulableContext context)
{
    new MyClass(/*parameters*/).doStuff(/*parameters*/);
}
```

Comment: It was quick. Thank you for your valuable input. :)